# How to reshape the array to (X,1,3) to (X,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data which is list with len of 5000

I have changed the list into numpy array. I got the numpy array with shape(5000,1,3)

I need to reshape this to shape(5000,3)

Can i directly change list with
`array([[0.3, 0.3 0.3]], dtype=float32),`
`array([[0.3 , 0.3, 0.3 ]], dtype=float32),`
`array([[0.3, 0.3  , 0.3 ]], dtype=float32),`

Can i change it to below format
`array([[0.3,0.3,0.3],`  
`[0.3,0.3,0.3],`  
`[0.3,0.3,0.3]],dtype =float32)`

Comment: my_array.reshape(5000,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reshape() as example below:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6]]], dtype=np.float32) # a with shape (2,1,3)
print(a.shape)
b=a.reshape(2,3) # change to (2,3)
print(b)
print(b.shape) #b with shape (2,3)
```

See also the example below to directly change list [np.array([[0.3, 0.3,0.3]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([[0.3 , 0.3, 0.3 ]],dtype=np.float32)] with shape (2,1,3) into numpy array with shape (2,3)

```
import numpy as np
a=[np.array([[0.3, 0.3,0.3]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([[0.3 , 0.3, 0.3 ]],dtype=np.float32)] 
print(a)
b=np.array(a) #b with shape (2,1,3)
print(b.shape)
c=b.reshape(2,3)
print(c)  # c with shape (2,3)
```

Comment: also an option: `b = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[0], 1, a)`

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive *Numpy* method to get rid of dimensions of size *1*
is *squeeze*.

So you can run:

```
b = np.squeeze(a)
```